# How can i move 500K records from SQL to Salesforce using Bulk Api?

Tags: rest-api, salesforcedx, c#

Is there a step by step example , preferably in c# , which shows how I can move over half a millions records from sql table to a Salesforce entity, namely Account using the Rest Bulk Api ?
I have setup a connected app , and have the tokens , can login and perform a select quey , but I would like to be able to perform a create of these records by selecting from the sql table.

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    private static SalesforceClient CreateClient()
    {
        return new SalesforceClient
        {
            Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"],
            Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"],
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"]
        };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = CreateClient();

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            client.Login();
            Console.WriteLine(client.Query(args[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            client.Login();
            Console.WriteLine(client.Describe("Account"));
            Console.WriteLine(client.Describe("Contact"));
            Console.WriteLine(client.QueryEndpoints());
            Console.WriteLine(client.Query("SELECT Name from Contact")); 

           // can i create here since i have the instance ?                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

SalesforceClient.cs

```
public class SalesforceClient
{
    private const string LOGIN_ENDPOINT = 
    "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";        
    private const string API_ENDPOINT = "/services/data/v25.0/";


    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
    public string InstanceUrl { get; set; }

    static SalesforceClient()
    {            
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
    }
    
    public void Login()
    {
        String jsonResponse;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", "password"},
                    {"client_id", ClientId},
                    {"client_secret", ClientSecret},
                    {"username", Username},
                    {"password", Password}                        
                }
            );
            request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");                
            var response = client.PostAsync(LOGIN_ENDPOINT, request).Result;
            jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Response: {jsonResponse}");
        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonResponse);
        AuthToken = values["access_token"];
        InstanceUrl = values["instance_url"];
        
    }

    public string QueryEndpoints()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string restQuery = InstanceUrl + API_ENDPOINT;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }

    public string Describe(string sObject)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string restQuery = InstanceUrl + API_ENDPOINT + "sobjects/" + sObject;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }

    public string Query(string soqlQuery)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string restRequest = InstanceUrl + API_ENDPOINT + "query/?q=" + soqlQuery;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restRequest);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use SalesforceDX to load data into sandboxes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218755/can-i-use-salesforcedx-to-load-data-into-sandboxes)

Comment: Export to CSV and then use `sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert` to upsert. See referenced answer for details.

Comment: I have written a c# app that allows me to login and perform selects... I was looking at extending the app to allow create, update , delete of entities in Salesforce by setting up a rest request

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Post your attempt (C# code)

Comment: If i post code here , for some reason it doesnt format correctly. I will post in my question above.