# Initialise Salesforce sandbox from a static dataset

Tags: sandbox, data

I have a scenario where a sandbox is used for training purposes and needs the data to be reset and reinitialised from a static dataset for each training session.

What would be the recommended approach for this?

Comment: A simpler alternative to the above is script the data load on a newly created sandbox via a tool - [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm), [SFDMU](https://help.sfdmu.com/key-features), [sfdx](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218755/can-i-use-salesforcedx-to-load-data-into-sandboxes) and many others,

Comment: There are several open-source and paid tools that might meet your needs, search for "salesforce populate sandbox with data"